# Sci-fi anime set in space with a spaceship on the run from bad guys

Tags: story-identification, anime, space

I’m looking for a 90's -00's anime I saw on TV on a channel called Spacetoon about 17 years ago. Here is what I remember from it:

It’s set in space and centers around the crew of a spaceship that is always on the run from the bad guys. The majority of crew are women, and the main character is a woman. In one episode they buy a turret from a junk dealer. The turret looks like its from a ww2 battleship and attach it to the button of the spaceship, which is strange since the ship has all kinds of laser weapons.

One of the bad guys is a old bald man with a very long white beard. After failing his superiors one time too many he is punished by being imprisoned and having hundreds of red tubes stuck into his body. In a later episode we learn that he is being used as a power source for the bad guys new superweapon that can teleport bombs into enemy ships and instantly destroy them from within. There is a lot of build up to this, but the superweapon is destroyed the first episode it's used.

Comment: In what country did you see this channel?

Comment: https://spacetoontv.fandom.com/wiki/Toon_Space_Cartoons#Anime is it any of the shows in this list? This was the only TV channel called "Spacetoon" I could find, and it very handily has a list of shows which aired on its channel. Not sure if it's 100% reliable, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that it is [*Lost Universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Universe#Anime).

Here is a bio of the bald guy with a long white beard (quoted from the [Roy Glen page of KanzakaDex](https://kanzaka.fandom.com/wiki/Roy_Glen)):

> **Roy Glenn** (Japanese: 紅蓮翁 Rōmaji: guren okina) was a member of the Nightmare Syndicate with a role of strategist.
>
> He tried numerous times to capture or kill Kain Blueriver but even when working with Kali, he failed (and also failed to kill her too). As punishment, the Spreader of Darkness had him forcibly absorbed by Nezard.
>
> He died when the Swordbreaker destroyed Nezard.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be *Angel Links*, this series takes place in the "Outlaw Star" Universe.

[image: Angel Links poster showing the main characters: 3 girls, a cat like character and a wolf/dragon humanoid]

Comment: Ignoring the fact that OP already accepted another answer, can you make some effort to explain why you think this is the correct answer?